# How to add fields to a get request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have most of the puzzle working with the facebook graph api.
I have this part functioning.

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me',
auth: {
  'bearer': req.body.token.access_token
}
```

This returns

```
{statusCode: 200, body: "{"name":"Jason Basanese","id":"my-id"}", headers: Object, request: Object}
```

Which is what I would expect. However I get a problem when I try to do something like this:

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/email',
auth: {
  'bearer': req.body.token.access_token
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{statusCode: 400, body: 
"{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/email","type":"OAuthException",
,"code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"my-trace"}}", headers: Object, request: Object}
```

Any ideas on how I could make the second request return an email instead of an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change is as simple as this:

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email',
```